# Updating Heroku database without deleting anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have my project in production right now using Heroku, but I want to add more tables and such to my rails database and than push it to Heroku. And I also plan on upgrading to Rails 5.

Are there any general rules that I should or shouldn't be doing so that my existing databases of Users does not accidentally get deleted?

Also, i noticed that Heroku has a 'backup' feature. Does this backup feature save a copy of all my Users information (email, name, pw, ect) which I can restore back at any certain time in case the unthinkable happens?

Comment: what abou Migrations? - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you should be using [Heroku's PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups). This will let Heroku take a snapshot of your database at set intervals every day, and store the backups on Amazon S3 so you can download or restore them at any time.

This is nice, because if you accidentally delete some data, or make some major changes and need to 'revert them', you can easily use the Heroku CLI tool to restore backups =)